# How to include header files in CAPL test module

Tags: capl

I am creating CAPL Test Module in Canoe11. I wanted to create different files for variables , user defined functions in separate file and then include in my CAPL test Module. In which format it should be written so I can reuse it in different test modules?

Answer (score 0):

They usually have *.cin extension. 
Simplest way you can include them in *.can CAPL Test Modules is by File Explorer. Right click on Includes tab and "Add include...".

[image]

If you are code-savvy enough, you can manually define it in the

```
includes
{
}
```

section of the .can file, like this:

```
#include "[absolute/relative path to the .cin file]"
```

Comment: to my experience, *.cin and *.can can be included just fine. If there were noticeable differences, I failed to spot them. This being said, I always preferred *.cin for header files.